# “Unable to get a Window, abort” running kivy app

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, kivy

I'm just starting out with kivy and I can't get over this error.
I'm using pycharm.

```
[CRITICAL] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider. Please enable debug logging (e.g. add -d if running from the command line, or change the log level in the config) and re-run your app to identify potential causes
sdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _window_sdl2: The specified module could not be found.
[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
```

Here's my code:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class MyApp(App):
def build(self):
    return Label(text="Hello world!")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It's working for me (win10 64bit, Anaconda). Which OS\Python version are you using?

Comment: python 3.8, windows 10

Comment: What's Anaconda?

Comment: Anaconda is a Python distribution that includes a lot of libraries and the Spyder IDE: https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual  I ran your code without Anaconda and it still worked.Check this page for possible solutions: https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/5677